# Measuring voltage 10 times every second with HP 34401A DMM

Tags: multimeter

I'm trying to measure voltage continuously for a short time using the HP 34401A digital multimeter. To do this I have connected the DMM to my PC via RS-232. The PC is running Windows 10 and I use Termite which is a serial monitor. With this setup I can control the DMM remotely without errors.

Now I want to measure the voltage 10 times per second and receive the readings by the PC. I used the following setting.

```
VOLTage:DC:RANGe 0.1
VOLTage:DC:RESOlution 0.0001 
SAMPle:COUNt 1
TRIGger:COUNt 10
TRIGger:DELAy 0.1
```

(Trigger source is 'Immediate' by default. I didn't change it)

The DMM sends 10 values to PC, when I send 'READ?' command. But I have no idea the actual sampling rate. With the trigger source of 'immediate' and the trigger delay of 100ms. Can I expect that my sampling rate will be 10samples/seconds ?

If the above setting is valid. Could I achieve a sampling rate of 100 samples/seconds too?

Comment: You will have to lookup the throughput rate in the datasheet, but for ascii over rs232 you won't get 100Hz constant streaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out from the manual;

:NPLCycles?

- Or choose 1 cycle for 50Hz sample rate or 20ms integration time
- or 10 cycles (PLC) for a 5Hz sampling rate or 200ms integration time

  - ( if you are in 50 Hz land ;)

I guess if you want a 10 sample/s rate it is NPLC=1 and Delay = 80ms

:NPLCycles {0.02|0.2|1|10|100|MINimum|MAXimum}

Select the integration time in number of power line cycles for the present
function (the default is 10 PLC). This command is valid only for dc volts,
ratio, dc current, 2-wire ohms, and 4-wire ohms. MIN = 0.02. MAX =
100.

For 1k readings/s

```
*RST
*CLS
DISPlay OFF
FUNCtion ""
:RESolution MAXimum
:NPLCycles MINimum
ZERO:AUTO OFF
:RANGe:AUTO OFF
CALCulate:STATe OFF
TRIGger:SOURce IMMediate
TRIGger:DELay 0 
READ?
```